Am I doing a mistake in using equality operator?
I am trying to solve a problem without recursion and loop. Problem is to check if the entered number is equal to 2^x where x is positive integer. It is working fine except for a number 536870912.
I was expecting to get true printed but false gets printed.
#include<stdio.h>
    #include<math.h>
    int main()
    {
        long int num;
        printf("Enter a num: \n");
        scanf("%ld", &num);
        double s = log(num)/log(2);
        int a = s;
        double b = a;
        //printf("%lf %lf\n", s, b);
        if ( s == b)
        {
            printf("true");
        }
        else
        printf("false");
        return 0;
    }

It is not a floting point problem I printed the value of s and b they are same 29.000000 for 536870912.
please help.

sorry, no, I  printed the value of s and b they are same 29.000000 for 536870912

Include your compilation flags, but the linked duplicate is very likely your answer.

printf with %.15lf (or more) and you'll see it's not EXACTLY 29, just so close that the default 'precision' of 6 rounds to 29. PS: old hacker trick (from the days when hacking was good) is (num & (num-1)) == 0 or equivalently (num & ~ - num) == 0 -- try it.

golu@golu-Aspire-E5-511:~/Desktop/c$ ./ex38.exe
Enter a num:
536870912
29.000000 29.000000
false

Difference is at the 15th decimal digit: https://godbolt.org/z/TYqWcxGr4
